# Parsing Diskpart output with .NET

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, parsing

I am writing a program which needs to parse output result from windows command "diskpart", particularly in parsing disk & volume information (using "list disk" & "list volume") out with VB.NET

I managed to use diskpart output the results into a text file by using the dos command `diskpart /s myscript.scp > result.txt`

Now in VB.NET I need to parse 'result.txt' to retrieve 'volume number', 'drive letter', 'drive label', 'type', 'size' & 'size_unit' into an array for further processing.

What is the best method to retrieve all these data? I try reading at MSDN about .NET regular expressions (Regex), it make me confuse and not sure  what the pattern should be used in my case.

Hope someone could help me out, any alternative parsing method is welcome.

***Update 26 Jun 2013 - for some technical reason, I need to stick with "diskpart" and rely on it's output results for parsing.**

**Example of input (result.txt)**

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: PC1

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1863 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         7424 MB      0 B

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     C   SYSTEM       NTFS   Partition    100 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     D   TEMP         NTFS   Partition   1606 GB  Healthy    Pagefile
  Volume 3     G                       Removable       0 B  No Media
  Volume 4     F   GSFKEY       NTFS   Removable   7423 MB  Healthy
```

**Output**

```
disk(0)
 .disknum=0
 .size=1863
 .size_unit="GB

disk(0)
 .disknum=1
 .size=0
 .size_unit="B"

..and so on

vol(0)
 .volnum=0
 .letter="E"
 .label=""
 .type="DVD-ROM"
 .size=0
 .size_unit="B"

vol(1)
 .volnum=1
 .letter="C"
 .label="SYSTEM"
 .type="Partition"
 .size=100
 .size_unit="GB"

..and so on
```

Comment: Is the technical reason "I need to make sure my code is brittle if they ever changed the output format of `diskpart`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first create a class that represents your data:

```
Public Class DiskPartResult
    Public Property Volume As String
    Public Property Number As Int32
    Public Property Ltr As String
    Public Property Label As String
    Public Property Fs As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property SizeUnit As String
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property Info As String
End Class
```

Now you can use `File.ReadLines` with following Linq query to get the relevant data lines:

```
Dim diskPartFileLines = File.ReadLines("Results.txt")
Dim dataLines = From line In diskPartFileLines
                Skip While Not line.TrimStart().StartsWith("----------") Skip (1)
                Take While line.TrimStart().StartsWith("Volume")
```

Now you can fill a `List(Of DiskPartResult)`:

```
Dim alldata = New List(Of DiskPartResult)
For Each line As String In dataLines
    Dim columns = line.Trim().Split({vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If columns.Length <> 9 Then Continue For
    Dim data = New DiskPartResult()
    data.Volume = columns(0)
    data.Number = Int32.Parse(columns(1))
    data.Ltr = columns(2)
    data.Label = columns(3)
    data.Fs = columns(4)
    data.Type = columns(5)
    Dim sizeInfo = columns(6)
    data.Size = Double.Parse(sizeInfo.Split()(0).Trim())
    data.SizeUnit = sizeInfo.Split()(1).Trim()
    data.Status = columns(7)
    data.Info = columns(8)
    alldata.Add(data)
Next
```

If you want to output it:

```
For Each dpr As DiskPartResult In alldata
    Console.WriteLine("vol({0})", dpr.Volume)
    Console.WriteLine("   .volnum={0}", dpr.Number)
    Console.WriteLine("   .letter={0}", dpr.Ltr)
    Console.WriteLine("   .label={0}", dpr.Label)
    Console.WriteLine("   .type={0}", dpr.Type)
    Console.WriteLine("   .size={0}", dpr.Size)

    ' and so on ... '
Next
```

---

> apparently, the separator is not a tab-character, is all spaces. Any
>   ideas?

Then you could "split" on the double-white-space indices which you can get from the header-line, because the data lines are using the same indices.

I have created following extension method to get all indices for a given seperator string in a text:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function AllIndexOf(text As String, str As String, comparisonType As StringComparison) As IList(Of Integer)
    Dim allIndeces As IList(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf(str, comparisonType)
    While index <> -1
        allIndeces.Add(index)
        index = text.IndexOf(str, index + str.Length, comparisonType)
    End While
    Return allIndeces
End Function
```

Now you can use  this code to query the required informations:

```
Dim diskPartFileLines = File.ReadAllLines("Results.txt")
Dim headerLine = (From line In diskPartFileLines
                  Skip While Not line.TrimStart().StartsWith("----------")).First().Trim()
Dim colStartIndices As IList(Of Int32) = headerLine.AllIndexOf("  ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
Dim dataLines = From line In diskPartFileLines
                Skip While Not line.TrimStart().StartsWith("----------") Skip 1
                Take While line.TrimStart().StartsWith("Volume")
                Select line.Trim()
Dim alldata = New List(Of DiskPartResult)
```

Then enumerate the query, initialize the `DiskPartResults` and add them to the list:

```
For Each line In dataLines
    Dim data = New DiskPartResult()
    Dim lastIndex = 0
    For i As Int32 = 0 To colStartIndices.Count - 1
        Dim index = colStartIndices(i)
        Select Case i
            Case 0
                data.Volume = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 1
                data.Number = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim())
            Case 2
                data.Ltr = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 3
                data.Label = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 4
                data.Fs = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 5
                data.Type = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 6
                Dim sizeInfo = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
                data.Size = Double.Parse(sizeInfo.Split()(0).Trim())
                data.SizeUnit = sizeInfo.Split()(1).Trim()
            Case 7
                data.Status = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
            Case 8
                data.Info = line.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex).Trim()
        End Select
        lastIndex = index
    Next
Next
```

Note that the `For Each` is not tested but it should give you the idea.

Comment: If the seperator is not the tab-character you have a problem. Because it's difficult to detect the new column(`String.Split()` would even split "Disk 0" into two columns).

Comment: apparently, the separator is not a tab-character, is all spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: I have issue executing the code, what is 'headerLine'? and does the code still works with volumes that doesn't have 'drive ltr' and 'label'?

Comment: Sorry, I have mistakenly omitted the headerline-Query. I will add it later.

Answer (score 5):

Can you get this information from System.IO.DriveInfo?

```
public DriveInfo(string driveName);


    public long AvailableFreeSpace
    public string DriveFormat
    public DriveType DriveType
    public DirectoryInfo RootDirectory
    public long TotalFreeSpace
    public long TotalSize
    public string VolumeLabel
    public static DriveInfo[] GetDrives();
```

Comment: for some technical reason, I need to stick with dispart

Comment: What is the technical reason?  Have you been told 'the only way to do it is parsing a text file'?

Comment: it was design requirement by another team, most likely is because diskpart will be use in executing disk partitioning in the process...so supplying correct & consistent 'disk number' is critical in this case

Comment: Do you believe that diskpart is responsible for assigning the `disk number`? And if it was, is it *documented* to be consistent in assigning those numbers?

Comment: Is it because 'the other team' didn't know about DriveInfo?  TBH, I didn't until your question came up :-)

Answer (score 1):

'Get Disk Number
            Dim query
            Dim objWMI
            Dim diskDrives
            Dim diskDrive
            Dim partitions
            Dim partition ' will contain the drive & partition numbers
            Dim logicalDisks
            Dim logicalDisk ' will contain the drive letter
            Dim stroutput As New StringBuilder

```
        objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        diskDrives = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive") ' First get out the physical drives
        For Each diskDrive In diskDrives
            query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + diskDrive.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" ' link the physical drives to the partitions
            partitions = objWMI.ExecQuery(query)
            For Each partition In partitions
                query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition.DeviceID + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"  ' link the partitions to the logical disks 
                logicalDisks = objWMI.ExecQuery(query)
                For Each logicalDisk In logicalDisks
                    stroutput.Append(logicalDisk.DeviceID & " - " & partition.Caption)
                    '  Wscript.Echo(logicalDisk.DeviceID & " - " & partition.Caption)
                Next
            Next
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(stroutput.ToString)
```

Comment: The output will display the Disk Numbers as used in Diskpart, as well as the disk info and partition info.